# In PHP is there a difference between foreach syntax

Tags: php, foreach

Is there any reason to use one `foreach` syntax instead of another?

```
foreach (array_expression as $value) {
    // statements
}
```

or

```
foreach (array_expression as $value) :
    // statements
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

They are completely equivalent, as stated in the official manual of PHP. 
See here for more info:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

Most times the `foreach ... endforeach` version is used in "templates". So it's easier for you to follow the logic of templates.